# Problema con .json como respuesta de una peticion Post NodeJS

Tags: java, json, nodejs

Estoy desarrollando un backend con una base de datos en mongoDB, al definir un endpoint de tipo post y probarlo en postman me envía un error en la consola y en postman no obtengo el objeto que definí como respuesta al post, sin embargo, si realiza la inserción correctamente en la base de datos.

mi versión de node es la **v14.5.0**

esta es la ruta definida para el endpoint

```
/*
    /api/hospitales
*/
const { Router } = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');
 
const {
    getHospitales,
    crearHospital,
    actualizarHospital,
    eliminarHospital
} = require('../controller/hospitales_controller');
 
const { validarCampos } = require('../middlewares/validarCampos_middleware');
const { validarJWT } = require('../middlewares/validarJWT_middleware');
 
const router = Router();
 
router.get('/', [], getHospitales);
 
router.post('/', [
    validarJWT,
    check('nombre', 'El nombre del hospital es necesario').not().isEmpty(),
    validarCampos
], crearHospital);
 
router.put('/:id', [], actualizarHospital);
 
router.delete('/:id', [], eliminarHospital);
 
module.exports = router;
```

este es el controlador que tiene la funcion de realizar el posteo a la bd

```
    const { response } = require('express');
 
const Hospital = require('../model/hospitales_model');
 
const crearHospital = async(req, res = response) => {
 
    const uid = req.uid;
    const hospital = new Hospital({
        usuario: uid,
        ...req.body
    });
 
    try {
 
        const hospitalDB = await hospital.save();
 
        res.json({
            ok: true,
            hospital: hospitalDB
        });
 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'Hable con el administrador'
        });
    }
 
};
```

este es el modelo que utilizo para crear el documento en la base de datos

```
    const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
 
const HospitalSchema = Schema({
 
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    usuario: {
        required: true,
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario'
    }
 
}, { collection: 'Hospitales' });
 
HospitalSchema.method('toJSON', function() {
    const { __v, ...object } = this.toObject();
    return object;
});
 
module.exports = model('Hospital', HospitalSchema);
```

este es el middleware que valida el JWB

```
const validarJWT = (req, res, next) => {

//leer token
const token = req.header('x-token');

if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: 'No hay token en la peticion'
    });
}

try {
    const { uid } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.uid = uid;
    
    next();

} catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: 'Token invalido'
    });
}

next();
```

este es el error en consola, aparentemente no estoy controlando algo

[image: Error en consola]

este es el resultado en postman, obtengo como tal un error confuso por que es codido 400 como si la ruta misma no estuviese definida
[image: resultado en postman]

Y aquí puedo ver que la petición si se realiza correctamente al revisar en la BD y ver el registro posteado

[image: BD de mongoDB]

Answer (score 0):

resuelto, Como muchos de los problemas de código que existen era simplemente un llamado extra de la funcion next() en el middleware validarJWT que acompaña a la petición

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const validarJWT = (req, res, next) => {

//leer token
const token = req.header('x-token');

if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: 'No hay token en la peticion'
    });
}

try {
    const { uid } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.uid = uid;
    // next(); <------------ Este next sobraba
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: 'Token invalido'
    });
}

next();
};
```